# Пользовательские функции или классы из файла без загрузки всего файла

Tags: ооп, php

Доброго времени суток, задался вопросом, каким образом можно вызвать в скрипте РНР часть кода (функцию, класс) из другого файла. При относительно даже небольших проектах, получается так, что накапливается множество функций и классов. И если классы еще как-то можно выделить в файлы (каждый файл отдельно для класса), то функции нужно группировать.
Собственно вопрос, кто знает, как можно подгрузить отдельную функцию без подгрузки всего файла?

К примеру, файл библиотеки lib.php

```
<?php
class DBconnect {
   private $host;
   private $user;
   private $pass;

   function connetctToDB(){
   //...подключение к базе
   }
   //...другие методы
}

class Auth {
   private $login;
   private $pass;
   //... методы класса
}

//... Другие классы и функции
?>
```

А в других файлах, например, тот же index.php использовать не конструкцию `include/require`, а  такой вариант, что бы загружать определение только одного класса или функции.
Есть мысли?

Comment: Нашел кое что тут http://www.codeisart.ru/php-class-files-autoload/
не совсем конечно то о чем писал, но тоже полезно почитать. Поговаривают что от __autoload будут отказываться со временем, так что...
Изучаем вопрос дальше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для функций я бы сделал как-то так:

Создаем папку где будут храниться все функции, если функции нужно разбить по контексту - делаем это с помощью папок, допустим для каждой функции создается отдельный файл с ее названием, все что нам нужно написать это класс который на вход будет получать путь к функции и подгружать, т.е. в итоге получается что-то простенькое вида:

```
/* singletone */
class Functions {
  const ROOT = '/functions/';
  private static $_instance = null;
  private function __construct(){}
  private function __clone(){}

  public static function getInstance() {
    if( self::$_instance === null ) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
  }

  public function load( $path ) {
     $fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . self::ROOT . $path . '.php';
     return file_exists( $fullPath ) ? include_once( $fullPath ) : false;
  }
}
```

И того, используем как-то так

```
Functions.getInstance()->load( 'view/form' ); // загрузим функцию form из группы view
```

Ну вообщем как-то так, к тому-же этот класс можно было бы потом расширять, например добавить метод для загрузки какой либо "группы" целяком и т.д.

Если же речь идет о неком фронт контроллере для манипуляций вида `Functions::call('functionName', $param1, $param2)`, то тут нужно смотреть в сторону PHP Closure функций.  Т.е. сделать как-то так (загрузка функций из файлов в этом примере упущена):

```
class Functions {
    public static $methods = array(); // массива функций (Closure objects)
    public static function register( $functionName, $function ) {
        self::$methods[ $functionName ] = $function;
    }
    public static function call( $functionName ) {
        if( self::$methods[ $functionName ] ) {
            $func = self::$methods[ $functionName ];
            $args = array_splice(func_get_args(), 1);
            return call_user_func_array( $func, $args );
        }
    }
}

// пользоваться так, например
Functions::register('hello', function($username){
    echo 'Hello ' . $username;
});
Functions::register('buy', function($username){
    echo 'Buy ' . $username; 
})

Functions::call('hello', 'Vasya'); // -> hello Vasya
Functions::call('buy',   'Vasya'); // -> buy Vasya
```

Т.е. при написании любой функции просто пишете ее как:

```
Functions::register('functionName', function() {
     // function code here...
});
```

Таким образом, при инклуде, функция регистрируется в статическом ассоциативном массиве класса Functions и становиться доступной для вызова вида

```
 Functions::call('functionName', param1, param2, param3, param4, ...);
```

Вам осталось только написать необходимое вам сочетание функционала из приведенных мною примеров в класс который лучше всего будет подходить непосредственно вам.

UPD

По поводу проксирования методов, можно просто написать __call функцию для класса и добавить proxy небольшой метод для класса Functions:

```
// метод класса Functions для облегчения проксирования
public static function proxy( $name, $args ) {
      if( self::$methods[ $functionName ] ) {
          $func = self::$methods[ $functionName ];
          return call_user_func_array( $func, $args );
      }
}

// ну и пример класса
class someClassName() {
    public function __call( $functionName, $args ) {
         Functions::call( $functionName, $args );
    }
}
```

теперь допустим мы создаем экземпляр этого класса. Допустим у нас зарегистрирована функция hello, а у класса someClassName ее естественно нет, тогда:

```
$obj = new someClassName();
$obj->hello( 1, 2, 3 );
// будет вызвана функция Functions::call('hello')
// с параметрами 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Отмечу его правильным. Мои знания еще не позволяют полностью и сразу осознать как именно реализовать этот пример. Но мысль я понял и теперь буду работать в этом направлении. Я только начинаю окунаться в ООП и использовать его на реальных проектах. Пока нет возможности проголосовать за ответ, на сайте я тоже недавно. Если все получится, постараюсь выложить свое решение

Comment: Тут не так ООП как нестандартное решение. Пожалуйста, удачи в изучении.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можете разбросать функции по файлам и подгружать их через класс-загрузчик (там же и группировать). Заодно сможете контролировать, чтобы один и тот же файл не подгружался дважды.

Comment: Об этом я уже думал. Все таки решения видимо такого прямого нет, придется для каждого класса создавать отдельный файл, а функции проще сгруппировать по назначению и тоже по файлам. Сейчас с пространством имен разбираюсь. Просто видел "элегантное решение" в CodeIgniter(фреймворк), где свои библиотеки можно размещать в каталоге application/libraries, а потом вызывать их динамически примерно вот так 
$this->load->library('someclass');
Можно конечно разобраться и с этим фреймворком, но не люблю загонять себя в "рамки" :) и подгонять необходимый результат или идею под "шаблон"

Answer (score 1):

Да собственно говоря вот так вот http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload.php

Если использовать акселераторы, включение файлов будет также ускорено.

Comment: Ушел в изучение. Акселераторы вряд ли кто-либо из хостеров даст поставить

Comment: @DimKabuki и пока не начали кодить, скажу, что функции можно делать статичными методами) То есть допустим есть у текстовые функции - прописываете autoload, а функции объявляете в чем-то типа модулей

    class mytxt {
      public static function someFunc() { /* ... */ }
    }

Тогда их можно загружать "помодульно", а в коде ничего включать не надо, просто первый вызов `<? echo mytxt::someFunc($text) ?>` сам загрузит этот модуль.

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз занялся аутолодом, на РНР.net написали:
"spl_autoload_register() предоставляет более гибкую альтернативу для автоматической загрузки классов. По этой причине использовать __autoload() не рекомендуется, а сама функция в будущем может перестать поддерживаться или быть удалена."
Поэтому перешел на изучение именно spl_autoload_register(). Хотя есть мнение, что он все же медленнее include и require
Как вариант думаю о классах в отдельных файлах и функциях по назначению. Плюс можно организовать класс для инклуда в зависимости скажем от id страницы (т.е. только то что необходимо)

Comment: Ушел в изучение. Акселераторы вряд ли кто-либо из хостеров даст поставить. Это да, потому что они сами все чаще и чаще ставят их сами.

Comment: @DimKabuki - естественно `__autoload` работает медленнее чем `include`. __autload это, так называемая, уличная магия и, естественно, работает медленнее решения "в лоб" в виде include.

Лично я, не смотря ни на что, считаю что лучше написать 2-3 строчки кода (руки не отвалятся), чем потом рассказывать "новоприбывшим" коллегам-новичкам как это работает, зачем это нужно и т.д. и т.п. (real story)