# Автозагрузка функций в PHP

Tags: php

Как можно реализовать автозагрузку функций из файла в PHP на подобие автозагрузки классов:

```
function __autoload($className) {
    $filename = $className . ".php";
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нативными средствами PHP - никак. Можно написать обвертку, singleton и поместить логику в функцию __call, который и будет подгружать функции, если в этом есть необходимость. Тогда, правда, прийдется писать что-то типа: `Methods::instance->func1()` и т.д.

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82916/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0) я описывал схему, там была несколько иная задача, но алгоритм похож.

Так-же существует PECL расширение [automap](http://phk.tekwire.net/joomla/support/doc/automap.htm), пишут что оно реализовывает автолоадинг функций, но я не юзал - ничего конкретного сказать не могу.

Comment: Ну вот automap здесь только и поможет. Только это расширение может обеспечить сходную функциональность с функцией автозагрузки классов.

Answer (score 0):

```
function call_func( $function, $args = array() ) {

    if( !function_exists( $function )){
        $parse = explode("_",$function);
        require( realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$parse[0]}.lib.php");
    }

    call_user_func_array($parse[1] , $args);

}
```

И вызовы всех ф-ий:

call_func('mylib_myfunction', array("three", "four"));

но это конечно изврат)

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
define("H", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/');
$opdirbase=opendir(H.'system/functions');
while ($filebase=readdir($opdirbase))
{
if (eregi('\.php$',$filebase))
{
require_once(H.'system/functions/'.$filebase);
}
}
```